# Infopath form to open once linked is clicked

Tags: infopath

I have an infopath form published already under sharepoint List.

What i want to do is when the link is clicked, the form will open upon in a browser - no need to go to list and click new just to fill out the form.

I am usingh infopath 2013 and my SP is 2016.

Thanks! hope someone can help ^^

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

1. Add Content Editor webpart
2. Add following code

> ```
>  <a href="http://SharePointSite/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://SharePointSite/FormLibrary/Forms/template.xsn&SaveLocation=http://SharePointSite/FormLibrary&ClientInstalled=false&DefaultItemOpen=1&Source=http://SharePointSite">Click Me</a>
> ```

Approach 2:

Add url in quick lauch

Update url with replacement of following Keyword:

- SharePointSite: Your SharePoint site url
- FormLibrary: Form library name
- Source: Update source with url where you want to redirect after
  submit the form.